# Expandable Text Simplification HTML

Tags: html, css, text, client-side

Would someone please point me towards an example code in HTML that takes the text in

```
 <h1>the text here in h1 tags</h1>
```

and turns it into a click activated text expand-er and collapse-r similar to the code in the first textbox: http://jdstiles.com/java/expandcollapsesections.html

Comment: this is fairly off-topic here.  SO would be better.  But, fwiw...

Comment: Sorry, I've used here for different questions and didn't think twice since it was related to some form of code.

Comment: @DougM when something is off topic and you think it should be migrated, please flag it for moderator attention (or accordingly if it just doesn't fit anywhere).  Suggesting another site often leads to the original poster posting a copy of it on the other site, which is less than ideal.

Comment: @user24527 In general, Programmers.SE is for questions of before coding starts, or high level architectural and pattern questions.  Stack Overflow is for errors while coding, and Code Review Stack Exchange is for how things can be done better after the code is complete (and working).

Comment: @MichaelT: Got it.  Under `flag`.  Is "not welcome in our community" better or "it needs moderator attention \ other"?

Comment: @DougM The 'moderator attention' one.  The "is not welcome" is intended for rather vile things (I haven't seen it here in P.SE, but other places...).  The "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate…" section expands to the close reasons (or duplicate search) which can help the people doing close votes make a better informed decision or have something brought to their attention (through the close vote review queue).

Comment: @MichaelT: Would it be reasonable to post in a new question: "Would someone please point me towards an example code in HTML that takes the text in <pre><code> <h1>**the text here in h1 tags**</h1> </pre></code> and turns it into a click activated text expand-er and collapse-r similar to this: http://jdstiles.com/java/expandcollapsesections.html??????

Answer (score 0):

> How would I change this code so that the text in `<h1>text</h1>` is the expand/collapse button instead of the word "expand/collapse" show up next to the header?

You wouldn't.  Instead, (and assuming you aren't after some CSS-only hack), you would define a client-side JS function to hide/show the related area, and attach it to an appropriate event on your H1 tags.

The exact method you would use depends on your goals.  But DOM manipulation like this, either via adding/removing CSS rules or direct properties, is the biggest reason to use JavaScript on the browser.  Do **NOT** copy and paste someone else's code into your own website if this is beyond your ability.  Use a framework or use this as a learning opportunity.

Comment: I understand the code to the extent that I can almost certainly guess the function of the line of code(sometimes with ten seconds of research in another tab...)... though writing it from scratch isn't something I've done yet. So far I gut earlier HTML from a website, and add what I want, piecing it together either by the simplest of coding from scratch (like using <p></p> and the simple stuff) or finding it on another page of the same website, find the exact code I need, and copy and paste... My goal is to make it so that only the titles show originally, and once you click the title,

Comment: the info pops into view underneath it, stretching the page.